# Unexpected virtual host behavior of Drupal sites on Apache

Tags: apache, drupal, drupal-7, virtualhost

I'm running an Apache server on a CentOS 7 machine.

A month ago I created a new Drupal site (let's call it *site1*) under `/var/www/html/site1`.
Visiting `http://<server-ip>/site1` yielded *site1* correctly.

Today, in order to provide a test environment for a new customer, I had to create a virtual host for a new Drupal site (let's call it *site2*).

So I created the following vhost rule:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin test@email.com
        ServerName site2.dev
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site2
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

After that I created the site's folder `/var/www/html/site2` and installed Drupal. Visiting `http://site2.dev` yields *site2* correctly.

The problem is, if I now visit `http://<server-ip>/site1`, *site2* is shown.

I can't figure out what might be the problem. The two sites are on completely different paths and different databases, so one shouldn't affect the other in my opinion.

Since I literally defined my first vhost today, I was wondering if someone might help me explain the issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is apache redirecting your request to the site1 or 2 files, regardless of the database or whatever. So if you tell apache to point all (*) http requests to the site2 directory it is normal that only site2 can be seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I missunderstood your problem and thought you had 2 domains.

Was your site1 accessed by the IP with no sub directory? In this case :
Change the DocumentRoot to point to /var/www/html then both sites will be accessed by IP/site1 and IP/site2.

If you were allready accessing site1 by the url IP/site1 then you had nothing to change and could access IP/site2 without your new virtualhost wich point only to site2 directory... .

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what do you mean by _first virtualhost_. No virtual host was defined for _site1_, I just access it via IP, like `http://10.10.10.10/site1`.

Comment: Well you certainly had one defined in the apache conf by default (look for httpd.conf file). If you have no access to the apache conf in this case you could create a virtual host that point only to your second site url and not *.

Comment: Corrected my answer, hope it helps you more.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Laurent's answer, this is the configuration I ended up using:

```
# So all IP only paths continue to work
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
        ServerName 10.10.10.10          # Server's IP
        <Directory /var/www/html/>
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

# So site2.dev points to its folder
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site2
        ServerName site2.dev
        <Directory /var/www/html/site2>
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```